# Is there anyway to display UIAlertController ONLY when app launches?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

so I have the following code in the viewDidAppear section

```
let theAlert = UIAlertController(title: "SUP", message: "DAWG", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    theAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "sup!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(theAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't mind the messages, I just came up with them randomly :3

Okay, so is there anyway for me to ONLY display this message when the app launches? Because when I come back from another controller, this message pops up again.

Answer (score 3):

Set a flag to indicate if the message has shown or not.

```
// first check to see if the flag is set
if alertShown == false {
    // show the alert
    alertShown = true
}
```

For this behavior to persist through launches, and show only on FIRST launch, save to NSUserDefaults.

```
// when your app loads, check the NSUserDefaults for your saved value
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let alertShown = userDefaults.valueForKey("alertShown")
if alertShown == nil {
    // if the alertShown key is not found, no key has been set.
    // show the alert.
    userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "alertShown")
}
```

You can handle both of these in the root view controller `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Probably a matter of integrating this code and setting the flag properly

Comment: Hmm, don't think so. Do you get what I'm saying? I want a way when the screen loads I get the UIAlert, but when I tap to the other screen and go back to the main screen, the UIAlert shouldn't show up.

Comment: Yup. Basically when the screen loads, check if your `alertShown` variable is true. If not, show the alert and set your `alertShown` variable to true. (If you want that to persist through launches, save it to NSUserDefaults). If it's true, you don't need to show the alert.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me? Think you can do a sample project on Github?